# How do developers integrate GUI in android apps?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android app Development. Now i know that we can create a basic layout of android apps using XML.But how are the layout of complex android apps  developed?Are the layouts developed separately using some designing tools and then integrated with the activities written in java?Please forgive if the question is really dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even Engineers at Google uses same tools that are publicly available to us, from what I got to know.
The layouts are not designed using custom tools, mostly are written in `java` and `xml` , some of the advanced layouts you see are also custom programmed in java, this involves time and expertise.

If you are curious, you can have a look at the code of the **Google I/O 2015 app** released few days back [here](https://github.com/google/iosched)